# Joining two string in powershell export to a text file

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I am trying to join two string in powershell and export to a file, but i am not getting desired result, i am quite new to powershell.

```
    $vm=Get-Content "c:\vmfile.txt"

ForEach($vm1 in $vm)
{
$boot="_boot.vhd"
$bname=$vm1+$boot 
write-output $bname+$boot | out-file "C:\rep.txt" -Append
}
```

For this I am expecting output of like in text file:

```
VM_boot.vhd
VM2_boot.vhd
VM3_boot.vhd
```

But result is like:

```
VM
VM2
VM3_boot.vhd
```

only the last line of the result is having correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make this a LOT simpler.

```
Get-Content "c:\vmfile.txt" | ForEach-Object {
   "$($psitem)_boot.vhd" | out-file "C:\rep.txt" -Append
}
```

PowerShell is all about objects and the pipeline, and this example features both.  PowerShell will read the file, and for each line in the file, run the chunk of code in the squiggles (curly braces).

Within the squiqqles, we're quoting our current object (using the $psitem pointer [but a lot of people use $_ instead, they mean the same thing]), and we're building the string we want to dump into the file.

Much simpler, and I think this is a better example of how PowerShell ought to be used.  Let me know if you have any questions about why this works :_

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this, not sure why you contatenated $boot twice:

```
$vm=Get-Content "c:\vmfile.txt"
$boot="_boot.vhd"

ForEach($vm1 in $vm)
{        
    $bname=$vm1+$boot 
    $bname | out-file "C:\rep.txt" -Append
}
```

Or more Powershellish like using ForEach-Object:

```
$vm=Get-Content "c:\vmfile.txt"
$boot="_boot.vhd"

$vm | ForEach-Object {
    $_ + $boot | out-file "C:\rep.txt" -Append
}
```

Ensure you initialize/create c:\rep.txt or it will just append